# Rails 4 model scope to created_at == current_month

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, model, scope

In my rails 4 model, I have this:

```
class PhoneContact < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates :phone_number, uniqueness: {scope: :call_type}
```

The idea is to ensure that each phone number on my `PhoneContact` model is unique, by call_type.

I also want to go one step further and add a "and the model was created this month" to this. So, my `phone_number` should be unique by `call_type` and `created_at == Time.now.month`.

How can I write that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `conditions` option for this:

```
validates :phone_number, uniqueness: {scope: :call_type, conditions: -> { where(created_at: Time.now.month) }}
```

Check the available options for **[uniqueness validation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validates_uniqueness_of)**